# claim based authorization + WPF desktop application

Tags: .net, security, claims-based-identity

I am trying to implement security model in a WPF desktop application in ver 4.5. I studied many articles and most of them are either Web based or with WCF.

Does that mean that claim based security is not actually made for desktop application?

Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claims based identity is a way to model identity - it is totally independent from the client/server environment.

You can always create a ClaimsPrincipal and populate some claims - and later query them.

Comment: how it is diff from RoleBased Security?

Comment: It is claims based ;) tinyurl.com/claimsguide2